# Godot OptionButton limit size of item list

Tags: user-interface, radio-button, game-engine, godot, gdscript

I am working on the GUI of my game right now and I have a question towards the OptionButton. When there are a lot of items in the OptionButton, the item list will start somewhere else in the screen and will go to the end of the screen which just looks awful. (picture 1). I would like to limit the size of the Item list and let it start where it normaly should start (picture 2). Also I would like to have a scrolling functionality in it after limiting the height of the item list (if it is not already the case after limiting the size). Does anyone know how to do this?

1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XbON.png
2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LQs7.png

Thanks in advance,
Orchi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish that by putting your options inside a `ScrollContainer`.

Here is the [Documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_scrollcontainer.html)

Comment: I just tried it but it does not seem to make a difference. I read somewhere that after clicking on an OptionButton, a Pop-up window with the items appears. I guess this is why this does not work. Unfortunately I can´t find a way to manipiulate this Pup-up item window.

Comment: Oh, I understand what you mean. You won't be able to change the popup, so you would have to roll your own. Probably by changing the OptionButtons to regular buttons and having them selectively hide a ScrollContainer with an ItemList inside of it. That would allow you to decide how big your itemlist is, it would scroll, and it would let you decide when it's visible.